# Convert and pass typedrow as parameter to custom rowdeleted event

Tags: c#

I have a base class for my custom strongly typed datatables. There I defined some events that can be overridden by the tables.
The base class is declared like:

```
public class RowEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public TypedRow Row { get; set; }
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TypedTable<TRow> : TypedTableBase<TRow> where TRow : TypedRow
{
    protected virtual void BeforeRowDeleted(RowEventArgs e) {}
```

There, in the update method I launch the delete event for each row:

```
    public virtual int Update()
    {
        foreach (var r in this.Where(r => r.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted))
        {
            var e = new RowEventArgs() {Row = r.GetItemArray(DataRowVersion.Original) as TRow};
            BeforeRowDeleted(e);
            if (e.Cancel) return;
        }

        //Commit changes to DB
    }
```

TRow is the type of the rows in the typed table, specified in the entity declaration

```
public sealed partial class Customer : TypedTable<CustomerRow>
```

And the event it's consumed in a partial class like:

```
protected override void BeforeRowDeleted(RowEventArgs e)
{
   //Do something for that customer before deleting it
   var myRow = e.Row as CustomerRow;
   var cust = myRow.CustomerID;
}
```

The problem I have is the cast to TRow is always null.
How I can pass the deleted row to the BeforeRowDeleted event so some actions can be made depending on that row's data?

Edit: Adding more declarations

```
public abstract class TypedRow : DataRow {}

public static object[] GetItemArray(this DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
{
    var count = (row.Table).Columns.Count;
    var items = new List<object>(count);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        items.Add(row[i, version]);
    }
    return items.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: are you saying that .GetItemArray(DataRowVersion.Original) as TRow is always null? How is GetITemarray defined?

Comment: GetItemArray is like .ItemArray but accepts datarow version.
 public static object[] GetItemArray(this DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
 It's a DataRow extension.

Comment: not helpful. CLR is saying that the return type of getitemarray is not a TRow. We cant see what GetITemArray returns so we cant say why it doesnt work. WHat does the debugger tell you is the return type

Comment: The debugger says: r.GetItemArray(DataRowVersion.Original) {object[8]} object[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static object[] GetItemArray(this DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
{
    var count = (row.Table).Columns.Count;
    var items = new List<object>(count);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        items.Add(row[i, version]);
    }
    return items.ToArray();
}
```

is returning a list of columns not rows. Items contains n* Row[i,x] which I doubt is also a row and so the cast to TRow will fail

Comment: Despite not being the solution, it pointed the problem, which allowed me to create a new typedrow method that returns a row. And that worked.